# Regex: Match x if not surrounded with y

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I try to make a regex (Python 3) which selects text if it is surrounded with delimiters but not if another delimiter is surrounding those. For example let aa be the outer and bb the inner delimeter. Then

```
   text

   bb
      some
      lines of text
   bb

   more text
```

Should only match

```
   bb
       some
       lines of text
   bb
```

But

```
   text
   aa

   bb
      some
      lines of text
   bb

   aa
   more text
```

Should match nothing as the "aa" delimeter should exclude its body from being matched.

I tried some combinations but only managed to match the "bb" body with

```
   bb(.|\n)*?bb
```

Is this even possible to do with regex? If so how would one use this?

Comment: It is done like this - ``re.findall(r'aa.*?aa|(bb.*?bb)', text, re.S)``, you may later filter out emoty elements with `list(filter(None, matches))`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew word boundaries should probably be added.

Comment: @ctwheels I consider `aa` and `bb` as placeholder patterns, and it is not so evident they start and end with word chars.

Comment: You can also use PyPi regex with `\ba{2}\b.*?\ba{2}\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bb{2}\b.*?\bb{2}\b` (making use of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`) as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/1a01bZ/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's fair. OP `\baa\b` if `aa` is a word (same goes for `bb`). If it's not, you can simply do as wiktor states and use `aa` without word boundaries.